# Connecting Power BI to ORacle? Filling out TNSNames.ORa

Tags: oracle, powerbi, crm

We are using Oracle cloud CRM. Our organization has been using it since quite few years and the people who set it up have already left. I am new here and am trying to connect the CRM data to Power BI. I intalled the ODAC drivers and everything. However, I do not know what to enter in my tnsnames.ora file. That file has asked for service name, server name and hostID/name. No one in the organization has this information. I reached out to Oracle support and here is the response they gave:

Oracle’s response to the service request: “These details are not found in Documentation because they cannot be provided. You'll need to reach out to Power BI support to see if there are alternate ways to create this integration without these details.”

Does anyone know why Oracle would not share these details with us? If there is any other way to find out the server and service name? How should I proceed in such scenarios.

As of now, we use a link to login to the service and we do not have much documentation

Answer (score 0):

Let me attempt to translate.

*We are using Oracle cloud CRM*

Oracle is hosting our application.

*I am new here and am trying to connect the CRM data to Power BI*

We want to query the database being used to store our application data.

*Oracle’s response to the service request: “These details are not found in Documentation because they cannot be provided..."*

This is where it gets fun, they are saying - we do not give clients direct access to the database where their data is hosted. So in other words, you CANNOT connect your tool directly to the database.

So, I think you're best bet, is to look into REST APIs that have been published for you as a subscriber to the service. This is often provided in lieu of providing direct access to your hosted environment.

Answer (score 0):

Your other bet is to contact someone in your organisation that has the oracle connections in a file which you could load SQL Developer by Oracle, and explore the connections there. Most likely this will be a data engineer or IT contact in your organisation who will have this information. Once you have the connection info visible, you can then enter this directly in Power BI after creating an Oracle connection.